# Add @var to SQL Insert into … values ( SELECT …[here] FROM … )

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose that I am copying one table data values into another table.

`INSERT INTO T1(field_list) VALUES( SELECT field_list FROM T2 )`

And instead of inserting one column of second table I provide a variable. It would be like

`INSERT INTO T1(field_list) VALUES ( SELECT field_list, @variable FROM T2 )`

Taking into consideration that there is no error with column count and instead of providing some static text I provide a variable name.

If I change @variable to some static text it works but not @variable.

How to provide @variable in that case ?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?  Do you get an error, or is the wrong data inserted?

Comment: Your should have no problems with that, please post the exact error message you encounter.

Comment: the field I'm inserting is NULL!!

Comment: my variable has been declared !

Comment: `SELECT @HCode2='....'
  INSERT INTO Flight(FCode, CCode, Bound, Origin, Destination, RP_BOARD, ETD, ETA, DepDate, ArrDate, RP_CARRIER, RP_STATUS, ChkSum)
  SELECT s.Code, 
  CASE s.Tpe 
  WHEN 'I' THEN c.ICAOCode 
  WHEN 'L' THEN c.LCode
  END AS CCode, s.Bound, s.Origin, s.Destination, 0, s.DEPTM, s.ARRTM, @iDate, @iDate, s.RP_CARRIER, 7, @HCode2 FROM Schedule s, Carrier c 
  WHERE s.RP_CARRIER=c.Code AND s.Code=@FCode2`

Answer (score 0):

You have to first declare the @variable

```
DECLARE @variable varchar(255)
SET @variable = 'myColumn'
EXECUTE (' SELECT *, ' + @variable + ' FROM myTable' )
```

Comment: my variable has been declared!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO T1(field_list) 
SELECT field_list, @variable FROM T2
```

It should work without any issue unless you table doesn't allow null and you have same number of values to be inserted as many columns defined in insert into statement.

As you said variable is declared, it shouldn't be a problem.

**EDIT:**

@Variable could be dynamic text that you pass from front end or static text assigned to variable in your SP. It should work in all the cases.

INSERT INTO T1(field1,field2)
SELECT field2, @variable FROM T2

Comment: made it work! the problem was function did not return hash! When I changed @var to some static text it worked !